# How can I add metaboxs to Admin Bar?

Tags: categories, metabox, tags, publish, admin-bar

Is there a way to add a metabox to the admin bar?

My goal is to be able to change the categories, tags and publish date / time, status & visibility of a post on the front end of any post/page.

I'd need to add the following to the Admin Bar:

1. Category Metbox
2. Tags Metbox
3. Publish Metabox

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont recommend that. Post edit action has many custom `filters` and `actions` binded to that, and if you will try to update post by a non-standard, custom method, then you may have some problems... 
I advice to go to default `EDIT` page, (or in worst case, try some plugins, named i.e. "Front Edit" plugins or etc...)

If you still need the way you say, then you have to build custom `<form>` within front-end admin bar, that i think, will be hard for you.